# How to proof that a joint pmf is legitimate and how to calculate the mariginal pmf?

Tags: probability, functions

I want to solve a question like this:
The joint probability mass function of (X,Y) is

$$
\ f(x,y) = c{\lambda^x\theta^y/y!(x-y)!}\,
$$
$$
y= 0,1,....x; x=0,1,2....
$$
where 
$$
\lambda,\theta>0
$$
(a) Determine the constant c that makes this a legitimate joint pmf.
(b) Find the marginal pmf of Y and identify this well known distribution by name and parameter.

I know that to find constant c to make this a legitimate pmf is setting the sum of the pmf equals to 1. But I'm stuck for the following steps. And I also want to know how to get the mariginal pmf of Y?
Could any one help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: First you need to know the summation limit: $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \sum_{y=0}^x f(x, y) = 1$ The inner summation can be tackled by Binomial Theorem.

Comment: Could yo explain more on how to go with the Binomial Theorem in this case? It appears that the pmf doesn't follow the formula of Binomial Theorem. Thank you! @BGM

Comment: It does follow the Binomial Theorem - first you need to figure out the binomial coefficient, and you may need to supplement some factorial to see that.